# Two solutions for a given problem when simplifying double radicals?

Tags: linear-algebra, factorial, radicals, nested-radicals

Given the following problem:

Simplify: 
$$\sqrt{8-2 \times \sqrt{15}}$$

This expression could be rewritten as:

$$\begin{align}\\
\sqrt{8-2 \times \sqrt{15}}&= \sqrt{5-2\times\sqrt{5\times3}+3}\\
 &=\sqrt{(\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3})^2}\end{align}$$

Now since this expression is in the form 
$\sqrt{a^2} = \lvert a \rvert$

It follows that both $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$ satisfy the expression above because they are equal to $a$ and $-a$ respectively.

The author (*Kunihiko Kodaira, Japanese Grade 10*) selects $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ as a correct answer.

Where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: $\sqrt3-\sqrt5=-(\sqrt5-\sqrt3)$. Kodaira has just selected the positive square root.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But when I'm simplifying an expression, how do I know which square root to select? What if i don't know wether the expression on the left hand side of the equation is positive or negative?

Comment: In the usual context of precalculus (and basically unless otherwise specified), the definition of the symbol "$\sqrt{\ }$" is: "for a non-negative real number $a$, $\sqrt{a}$ is the non-negative real number $b$ such that $b^2=a$" (in fact you wrote $\sqrt{a^2}=\lvert a\rvert$, not something else). Therefore, there is no such thing as "How do I know which root to chose?": the non-negative one, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$ \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{5}}>0$ by definition

so is is equal to $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3} >0$

Comment: Hold on! does this mean that $\sqrt{a}$ equals $+a$ by definition?

Comment: No, but by definition, $\sqrt{a^2}=+a$

Comment: Oh I see! In this case it was hard to see that $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$ have the same absolute value

Comment: @matthiasdv: To be more precise, by definition $\sqrt{x}\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}|=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ only.

$|\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}| \neq \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 0):

With real numbers, the square (positive) root of a square is the absolute value of the base of that square.

The fact that the "square goes with the root" we say it to the children.

Your logic is right, both are correct answers.

They probably saved the other answer to save on paper (or in bits)